# Thread don't reload DataGridView

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

I Have a DataGridView that should be reloaded by a Thread. But when the thread execute, the DataGridView blinks and don´t load the changes.

The interesting thing is that if I try the code on the thread without being on a thread (executing on the main thread) the DataGridView reloads fine!

Here's my code:

```
 public void reloadClients(object source, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Clients will reload.");
                dgvClientes.DataSource = null;
                loadReloadClients = new Thread(new ThreadStart(jobReloadAllClients));
                loadReloadClients.Start();
            }

            private void jobReloadAllClients()
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {             
                    descricaoCliente.Text = "CARREGANDO TODOS OS CLIENTES";      
                });

                System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = clientes.allClients().Tables["Clientes"];


                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    descricaoCliente.Text = "Todos os Clientes";
                    dgvClientes.DataSource = bs;
                    dgvClientes.Refresh();

                });

            }
```

## edit

As I was told to set the binding datasource on the main thread and load the BD data on the background thread....
Sievajet  this is what I got so far..

```
System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bs;
    public void reloadClients(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Clients will reload.");
        dgvClientes.DataSource = null;
        bs = new BindingSource();
        dgvClientes.DataSource = bs;
        loadReloadClients = new Thread(new ThreadStart(jobReloadAllClients));
        loadReloadClients.Start();
    }

    private void jobReloadAllClients()
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {             
            descricaoCliente.Text = "CARREGANDO TODOS OS CLIENTES";      
        });

        DataSet Setter = clientes.allClients();        
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            bs.DataSource = Setter.Tables["Clientes"];
            descricaoCliente.Text = "Todos os Clientes";
            //dgvClientes.DataSource = bs;
            //dgvClientes.Refresh();

        });

    }
```

Comment: Create and use one bindingsource on the main thread

Comment: How would I load clientes.allClients().Tables["Clientes"]; into the bindingSource? clientes.allClients().Tables["Clientes"]; its what consumes time

Comment: Load the datatable in the thread and assign the bindingsource.datasource with the invoke method

Comment: Did not work... I made the bindingSource as global variable, loaded the datatable in the thread and assigned the bindingsource.datasource with the evoke method and no results =(

Comment: Post what you've got

Comment: Actually, both versions of your code work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did it... for some reason, i had to deallocate the variable bs, and then initialize it again... now it works fine.

```
System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bs;
    public void reloadClients(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Clients will reload.");
        bs = null;
        dgvClientes.DataSource = null;
        bs = new BindingSource();
        dgvClientes.DataSource = bs;
        loadReloadClients = new Thread(new ThreadStart(jobReloadAllClients));
        loadReloadClients.Start();
    }

    private void jobReloadAllClients()
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {             
            descricaoCliente.Text = "CARREGANDO TODOS OS CLIENTES";      
        });

        DataSet Setter = clientes.allClients();        
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            bs.DataSource = Setter.Tables["Clientes"];
            descricaoCliente.Text = "Todos os Clientes";


        });

    }
```